# Debian recognizes usb-c docking station, but monitors do not work

Tags: debian, ubuntu, drivers, dock, displaylink

With Debian stable and proprietary drivers on a Lenovo x1 3rd gen--but not with MS windows 10 on an older Lenovo laptop (using the usb-c to usb-a) and a HP laptop (using usb-c)--I have a problem with the *ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock*: The USB-devices mouse, keyboard, and headset works fine; but the two monitors do not (akin to Pauxlo's [experience](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkPad-Hybrid-USB-C-with-USB-A-Dock-for-linux/m-p/4315328?page=2#5531196)). What to do?

1. forget about using this docking station (costly)
2. install Ubuntu (well, Debian is otherwise nice and installed)
3. try to make DisplayLink for Ubuntu [2](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) [3](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/679060) work on Debian (may be quite involved)
4. ask the question elsewhere e.g. on the displaylink forum, on the linux-hardware.org forum, et cetera.
5. other alternatives

I have found related issues, some which are solved, others which are still unsolved:

- detected on Debian 11 and Debian Testing with "snd_usb_audio" driver according to [linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:17e9-6015)
- [Debian Buster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676860/530603) with a link to solution for arch linux
- [solutions](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkPad-Hybrid-USB-C-with-USB-A-Dock-for-linux/m-p/4315328?page=1#5414383) and non-solutions [7](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkPad-Hybrid-USB-C-with-USB-A-Dock-for-linux/td-p/4315328) [8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625185/cannot-connect-external-monitor-via-usb-c-no-display-port-listed-in-xrandr-ub) for Ubuntu distributions
- [issue on Fedora, solution on RHEL8 and so on](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/t2tqje/lenovo_thinkpad_hybrid_usbc_with_usba_dock_is_not/)
- in case of high resolution, `apt-get install evdi-dkms libevdi0` has been suggested for Debian [10](https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/kg5d8p/comment/gh473yu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 011: ID 17e9:6015 DisplayLink ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was as follows, as shown by [Tall Paul Tech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SbVumPBpNQ)

1. download the latest [driver for Ubuntu](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) (not following [guide to unpack driver for other distros](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/679060), nor this [displaylink-debian](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian))
2. `unzip DisplayLink\ USB\ Graphics\ Software\ for\ Ubuntu5.6.1-EXE.zip`
3. `chmod 755 displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run`
4. `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run`

No reboot needed.

Comment: Worked for me. Reboot was required.